# Lifery portal connect to my own db

Tags: java, liferay

I want to manage my users login in my own database. Now we use liferay embedded database and we want to change and customize it.

Is there any document explaining how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it. Just check [this](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Database+Configuration).